# rails migration unique true but allow null values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I originally had this migration:

```
  def change
    add_column :users, :provider, :string, null: false, default: "email"
    add_column :users, :uid, :string, null: false, default: ""

    add_index :users, [:uid, :provider], unique: true
  end
```

But in my application, users can sign in with both omniauth and username and password without oauth authentication. As a result, in many situations, uid and provider will be null. So I created the following migration:

```
  def change
    change_column_default :users, :provider, nil
    change_column_default :users, :uid, nil
  end
```

But when I try to set the provider or uid to nil in Rails, I get a `PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR`:

```
u = User.first
u.provider = nil
u.save!
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1, "provider" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", 2017-08-16 00:01:34 UTC], ["provider", nil], ["id", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "provider" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains
```

It appears `unique: true` in the migration prevents setting null values. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the columns to **null: false** in your first migration which is causing the PG::NotNullViolation exception. That needs to be set to true to allow null values in both the columns. Writing a new migration to set null: true should resolve the issue as follows.

```
def change
   change_column_null :users, :provider, true
   change_column_null :users, :uid, true
end
```

Also below index may not work(RecordNotUnique exception raises as it is set unique: true) as you will have multiple rows having both uid and provider with null values. So this index need to be dropped.

```
add_index :users, [:uid, :provider], unique: true
```

Comment: undefined method `to_sym' for {:null=>true}:Hash when using change_column :users, :provider, null: true

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check it now, it should work if you are using rails 4.x version.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to this:

```
  def change
    change_column :users, :provider, :string, null: true
    change_column :users, :uid, :string, null: true
    remove_index :users, [:uid, :provider]
  end
```

which would subsequently allow null values but eliminate the two field constraint at the database-level, I did this at the model-level:

```
validates :provider, uniqueness: { scope: :uid }, allow_nil: true
```